# Show that the sequence $a_n = \frac{n }{\sqrt{10 + n}}$ is convergent or divergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Please explain how when dividing the numerator and denominator by $n$, the denominator turns into

$$a_{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{10}{n^2} + \frac{1}{n}}}$$

When dividing, I did $$a_{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{10 +{n}}} * \frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{n}}$$

Which gave the results,
$$a_{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{10}{n} + 1}}$$

Comment: You should show some effort or work posted here first.

Comment: @WangYeFei, done

Comment: For positive $n$, $\frac1n = \sqrt{\frac1{n^2}}$.

Comment: $$\frac{n}{\sqrt{10+n}}>=\frac{n}{\sqrt{2n}}=\sqrt n/\sqrt 2 \to\infty$$

Comment: @JacobAvenaim Your final result is incorrect.

Comment: @peterwhy, thank you!

Comment: @Gary, the final result is straight from the textbook

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $a_n > \dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{2}, n \ge 10$

Comment: The comment @peterwhy stated worked

Comment: Yeah, and my answer is also good too.

Comment: Wang, sorry, I was just confused by your answer.

Comment: Okay. From the fact that $a_n > \dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{2}$ you have $a_n \to \infty$.